# jquery Conditionally change sign of number in table based on value in anothe column

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I have a table with 3 columns (tradeID, BuySell and Lots). the lots columns contains a number , and  the BuySell column contains a b or n s. whats the bes tway to change the sign of th elots columns if the BuySell column contains a s?

Comment: Why are you not setting the 'sign' of Lots while you are preparing the data that will be bound to the table? Does your table's Buy/Sell column change dynamically in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/27gS2/3/

```
<table id='tblData' style="border: 1px solid #000000">
    <tr>
        <td>TradeID</td>
        <td>Buy/Sell</td>
        <td>Lots</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td>-30</td>
    </tr>
</table>


$("#tblData tr").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();

    if (text == "S") {
        var lot = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text());
        lot = lot * (-1);
        $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text(lot);
    }
});
```